# How to get the campaign performance report data with "Other" device type?

Tags: google-ads

Here is the report datas for campaign performance report:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<report>
    <report-name name='Campaign Performance Report'/>
    <date-range date='All Time'/>
    <table>
        <row campaignID='7762204259' budgetID='6581159701' campaign='Big Discount-Healthy and tasty Yogurt-37-1572424095385' campaignState='enabled' startDate='2019-10-31' endDate='2019-11-09' clicks='2' conversions='0.00' ctr='1.89%' cost='6337036' impressions='106' convRate='0.00%' avgCPC='3168518' viewThroughConv='0' costConv='0' advertisingChannel='Search' device='Mobile devices with full browsers'/>
        <row campaignID='2040534166' budgetID='2106066468' campaign='0621-Emma test-S P-55-1561109403886' campaignState='enabled' startDate='2019-06-22' endDate='2019-10-28' clicks='3' conversions='0.00' ctr='0.55%' cost='2330000' impressions='541' convRate='0.00%' avgCPC='776667' viewThroughConv='0' costConv='0' advertisingChannel='Search' device='Computers'/>
        <row campaignID='2040534166' budgetID='2106066468' campaign='0621-Emma test-S P-55-1561109403886' campaignState='enabled' startDate='2019-06-22' endDate='2019-10-28' clicks='2' conversions='0.00' ctr='3.03%' cost='5970000' impressions='66' convRate='0.00%' avgCPC='2985000' viewThroughConv='0' costConv='0' advertisingChannel='Search' device='Tablets with full browsers'/>
        <row campaignID='7762204259' budgetID='6581159701' campaign='Big Discount-Healthy and tasty Yogurt-37-1572424095385' campaignState='enabled' startDate='2019-10-31' endDate='2019-11-09' clicks='0' conversions='0.00' ctr='0.00%' cost='0' impressions='0' convRate='0.00%' avgCPC='0' viewThroughConv='0' costConv='0' advertisingChannel='Search' device='Devices streaming video content to TV screens'/>
        <row campaignID='7762204259' budgetID='6581159701' campaign='Big Discount-Healthy and tasty Yogurt-37-1572424095385' campaignState='enabled' startDate='2019-10-31' endDate='2019-11-09' clicks='0' conversions='0.00' ctr='0.00%' cost='0' impressions='26' convRate='0.00%' avgCPC='0' viewThroughConv='0' costConv='0' advertisingChannel='Search' device='Computers'/>
        <row campaignID='7762204259' budgetID='6581159701' campaign='Big Discount-Healthy and tasty Yogurt-37-1572424095385' campaignState='enabled' startDate='2019-10-31' endDate='2019-11-09' clicks='0' conversions='0.00' ctr='0.00%' cost='0' impressions='11' convRate='0.00%' avgCPC='0' viewThroughConv='0' costConv='0' advertisingChannel='Search' device='Tablets with full browsers'/>
        <row campaignID='2040534166' budgetID='2106066468' campaign='0621-Emma test-S P-55-1561109403886' campaignState='enabled' startDate='2019-06-22' endDate='2019-10-28' clicks='41' conversions='0.00' ctr='2.68%' cost='23530182' impressions='1528' convRate='0.00%' avgCPC='573907' viewThroughConv='0' costConv='0' advertisingChannel='Search' device='Mobile devices with full browsers'/>
        <row campaignID='2040534166' budgetID='2106066468' campaign='0621-Emma test-S P-55-1561109403886' campaignState='enabled' startDate='2019-06-22' endDate='2019-10-28' clicks='0' conversions='0.00' ctr='0.00%' cost='0' impressions='0' convRate='0.00%' avgCPC='0' viewThroughConv='0' costConv='0' advertisingChannel='Search' device='Devices streaming video content to TV screens'/>
    </table>
</report>
```

report definition for requesting the report:

```
{
    "selector": {
        "fields": [
            "CampaignId",
            "BudgetId",
            "CampaignName",
            "CampaignStatus",
            "StartDate",
            "EndDate",
            "Clicks",
            "Conversions",
            "Ctr",
            "Cost",
            "Impressions",
            "ConversionRate",
            "AverageCpc",
            "ViewThroughConversions",
            "CostPerConversion",
            "AdvertisingChannelType",
            "Device"
        ],
        "predicates": [
            {
                "field": "CampaignId",
                "operator": "IN",
                "values": [
                    2040534166,
                    7762204259
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Besides, I set `includeZeroImpressions` request header to `true` for including the zero impressions. I can get the zero impressions data row like: `Devices streaming video content to TV screens` device type.

But there is no report data row for `Other` device type.

WSDL: https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/reportdownload/v201809

Device type enum for campaign performance report: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-performance-report#device

Answer (score 1):

Google have discontinued the "Other" device type, or rather more accurately, renamed it to TV Screens.

All devices are now categorised as Computers, Tablets, Mobile Phones, or TV Screens. This is to make it simpler to understand, since any traffic that any traffic that doesn't immediately fall into these categories is going to be negligible.

This can be demonstrated by filtering any data through the Google Ads web interface using the Device filter. The options it gives you are the only options there are.

[image: Google Ads device selection]